# Integrity constraint violation: Duplicate entry '*****' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, zend-framework3

Im working on a project using zend framework and im designing a simple registration form. ive created a mysql db in phpmyadmin with column 'tel'(telephone number) as primary key. when testing the form on browser i have the following problem.

[image: pic1]

on submission i receive the error

[image: pic2]

[image: pic3]

whereas details are actually saved

[image: pic4].

i was supposing that zend framework imposes the use of 'id' as primary key but i dont have id on my table. i so, how can i ovveride or set primary key? 
or any other solution, thanks.

**Model files**

```
<?php
namespace Registration\Model;

class Registration
{
    public $fullName;
    public $userName;
    public $email;
    public $tel;
    public $gender;
    public $password;
    public $confirmPassword;

public function exchangeArray(array $data)
{
    $this->fullName     = ($data['fullName']) ? $data['fullName'] : null;
    $this->userName = ($data['userName']) ? $data['userName'] : null;
    $this->email  = ($data['email']) ? $data['email'] : null;
    $this->tel  = ($data['tel']) ? $data['tel'] : null;
    $this->gender  = ($data['gender']) ? $data['gender'] : !null;
    $this->password  = ($data['password']) ? $data['password'] : null;
    $this->confirmPassword  = ($data['confirmPassword']) ? $data['confirmPassword'] : null;
}


}

<?php
namespace Registration\Model;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGatewayInterface;

class RegistrationTable
{
private $tableGateway;
public function __construct(TableGatewayInterface $tableGateway)
{
    $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
}

public function saveRegistration(Registration $register)
{
    $data = [
        'fullName' => $register->fullName,
        'userName'  => $register->userName,
        'email'  => $register->email,
        'tel'  => $register->tel,
        'gender'  => $register->gender,
        'password'  => $register->password,
        'confirmPassword'  => $register->confirmPassword,
    ];

    $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
    $this->tableGateway->update($data);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using phone number as primary key is not a good idea at all. If you want to make sure that there are no multiple users with the same phone, just add an `unique` constraint to it.

By the way, why are you inserting AND updating the row at the same time? Or, why are you *always* inserting a row, when maybe it would be just an update?

My suggestion is: don't use phone as primary key. Add an id value to your model.

**Model**

```php
namespace Registration\Model;

class Registration
{
    public $registrationId;
    // ... And all other fields


public function exchangeArray(array $data)
{
    $this->registrationId = ($data['registrationId']) ? $data['registrationId'] : null;
    // And all other fields

}
```

**Model table**

```php
<?php
namespace Registration\Model;

class RegistrationTable
{

    public function saveRegistration(Registration $register)
    {
        $data = [
            'registrationId' => $register->registrationId,
            // ... And all other fields
        ];

        if(!$register->registrationId) 
        {
            // No registration id, it is an insert
            $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
            // If you want to have its id:
            return $this->tableGateway->lastInsertValue;
        }
        else 
        {
            // Ideally, here you'd also check if the row actually exists
            //
            // if(!$this->tableGateway->select(['registrationId' => $register->registrationId]))
            // {
            //    throw new \Exception('Element not found');
            // }

            $this->tableGateway->update($data, ['registrationId' => $register->registrationId]);
            // Return id to keep consistency (always return an int)
            return $register->registrationId;
        }
    }

}
```

**Don't forget to add it to your form!** Otherwise, you'll never end up doing the update (the `registrationId` will be lost in the process..).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I added a unique constraint on 'tel' on db in phpmyadmin but didn't work. Or if i'm to add the constraint in the code model in zend, how can i do that plz

Comment: concerning the registrationId, will be of type INT and AUTO_INCREMENT?